# Axios is returning undefined

Tags: node.js, reactjs, http, axios, nestjs

My API is returning proper data when I am requesting from Postman. Even API is getting properly called from React, I checked using `console.log` inside the controller, but I am always getting `undefined` response. I am not sure what the mistake is.

```
const submit = async (e: SyntheticEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const response = await axios
        .get('certificates', {
            params: { sponser },
        })
        .then((res) => {
            console.log(response); //undefined
            alert(res.status);  //200
            alert(res); //[object Object]
        });
};
```

Could you please help me on the same.

Comment: Are you saying that `console.log(response);` logs `undefined`? Or is the undefined response value elsewhere? `response` isn't defined in the `.then` function scope. What if you `console.log(res)` instead?

Comment: alert(res);  displaying [object Object]

Comment: `console.log(response);` should be producing a ReferenceError because you're trying to access `const response` because the declaration assignment has not finished *yet*. I don't see how you would be getting `undefined`. Or why you would be trying to log `response`, either, given that it's not assigned *yet*.

Comment: I am new to react. can you tell me how can print the same on page. I am submitting get request using form. now need to print the data below the form

Comment: thank you DrewReese, VLAZ . it worked. I modified after your suggestions.

Comment: @NiharikaS please mark as resolved if it worked. This will help others with the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return res in the then to have access on response:

```
const response = await axios
    .get('certificates', {
        params: { sponser },
    })
    .then((res) => {
        console.log(response); //undefined
        alert(res.status);  //200
        alert(res); //[object Object]
        // response is not defined here!
        return res;
    });
console.log(response);
```

Shorter way:

```
const response = await axios
    .get('certificates', {
        params: { sponser }
    });
console.log(response);
```

It seems that OP is relatively new to js - I can recommend this intro to async js: https://javascript.info/async-await